# Django forms difference, one works, the second one doesn't

Tags: python, django

I've got a kind strange problem. I've got two different (but almost the same forms and validation).
The validation in first one works, in the second one doesn't.
Can someone tell me why?

1)

```
class SignUpForm1(forms.Form):
test_value = forms.CharField(
    label='Your name',
    max_length=100,
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "input"})
)

def clean_test_value(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data.get('test_value')
    print(data)
    if data != "abc":
        raise forms.ValidationError("Error")
    return data
```

2. 

```
class SignUpForm2(forms.Form):
name = forms.CharField(
    label='name',
    max_length=100,
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "input"})
)

def clean_name_value(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
    print(data)
    if data != "abc":
        raise forms.ValidationError("Error")
    return data
```

View:

```
class SignUpView(View):
def get(self, request):
    form = SignUpForm1() #or SignUpForm2()
    return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form})
def post(self, request):
    form = SignUpForm1(request.POST) #or SignUpForm2(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print('valid')
    return render(request, "index.html", {"form": form})
```

And the html template:

```
enter code here<form action="" method="post" class="formField">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}
<button type="submit" class="btn-form">Test</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried printing data?

Comment: Yes, the first one prints the input, the second one doesn't

Comment: Well, if that would be wrong then both forms wouldn't work, i'll also update question with my view and html

Comment: I think that `clean_name_value` should be `clean_name`.  Since the method name doesn't correspond to the field name, it won't be called.

Comment: Thanks @StephenC, after changing name both of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation should be like that `clean_<fieldname>`. ([Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/))

In your case the function is  `clean_<fieldname>_value`.

so change the name of your function to just `clean_name`